# Does Go regexp support contiguous match?

Tags: regex, go

I found that some other languages support Contiguous Match anchor \G

The \G anchor specifies that a match must occur at the point where the previous match ended.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#contiguous-matches-g

But I found \G is an invalid token in Golang regex. What's the equivalent?

Comment: Get all matches and then check if each subsequent match starts at the expected position. It depends on what exact behavior you want to simulate.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `\G` is not supported. The [package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) state:

> The syntax of the regular expressions accepted is the same general syntax used by Perl, Python, and other languages. More precisely, it is the syntax accepted by RE2 and described at https://golang.org/s/re2syntax, except for \C.

And in RE2, `\G` is explicitly not supported, except for Perl:

> `\G   at end of last match (NOT SUPPORTED) PERL`

Among the methods of `Regexp` type, there isn't any that forces contiguous matches. If you absolutely must achieve this outcome, you'll likely have to write custom code.

---

Hacky demonstrative code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

const s = "foo,bar,baz,qu!ux,foox"

func main() {

    re, err := regexp.Compile(`\w+,?`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    matches := re.FindAllString(s, -1)

    var (
        split             int
        curidx            int
    )
    for _, m := range matches {
        if strings.Index(s, m) != curidx {
            break
        }
        curidx += len(m)
        split++

    }
    contiguousMatches := matches[:split]
    fmt.Println(contiguousMatches) // [foo, bar, baz, qu]
}
```